# Merging array of objects with the same key

Tags: json, jq

The problem:
I have N numbers of arrays of objects with the same identifying key within objects, and I'd love to merge those with `jq`.

This is a contrived example that attempts to illustrate the problem:

**From**

```
[
  {
    "google.com": {
      "http": {
        "dest_url": "http://stackoverflow.com"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "google.com": {
      "https": {
        "dest_url": "https://github.com"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "test.com": {
      "https": {
        "dest_url": "https://wikipedia.com"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**To**

```
{
  "google.com": {
    "http": {
      "dest_url": "http://stackoverflow.com"
    },
    "https": {
      "dest_url": "https://github.com"
    }
  },
  "test.com": {
    "https": {
      "dest_url": "https://wikipedia.com"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried with `jq '. | add' file` but it ended up with the following result.

```
{
  "google.com": {
    "https": {
      "dest_url": "https://github.com"
    }
  },
  "test.com": {
    "https": {
      "dest_url": "https://wikipedia.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `group_by()` of the keyname after doing `to_entries()` and form the final JSON from the grouped result

```
map(to_entries[])
| group_by(.key)[] 
| { (.[0].key) : map(.value)|add }
```

See it working on [jq-play](https://jqplay.org/s/k0c3l2Fvs4)

Answer (score 2):

A shorter alternative using `reduce` and recursive merging by `*` operator:

```
reduce .[] as $p ({}; . * $p)
```

<sup>[demo at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/IfD_UA31fO)</sup>